# Rewrite the sum using summation notation

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ -\sqrt3 +\sqrt4 -\sqrt5+\sqrt6 $$

Stuck on this question.. I thought it would have something to do with $i$, but that isn't the case.

My thought was something along the line of: $$ -\sqrt3 +\sqrt4 -\sqrt5+\sqrt6 \;=\;\sum_{n=3}^5 (\sqrt n )(i^n)$$

Comment: The "question" is unclear. Can you clarify it

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this website, bare with me. The question is to rewrite the sum using summation notation

Comment: "$-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{4},-\sqrt{5},\sqrt{6}$" is merely a collection of four numbers, or perhaps a sequence of four numbers.  It is certainly not a sum.  Perhaps you mean to ask "How can you rewrite $-\sqrt{3}\color{red}{+}\sqrt{4}\color{red}{+}(-\sqrt{5})\color{red}{+}\sqrt{6}$ using summation notation.  There are many ways to do that... the most trivial being as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^1(-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{6})$

Comment: It is probable that the *intended* solution (*though certainly not the only one*) is as $\sum\limits_{n=3}^6 (-1)^n\cdot \sqrt{n}$

Comment: What you have currently written has a weird equals sign that disrupts what is written causing it to make no sense.  $\sum\limits_{n=3}^5\color{red}{=}(\sqrt{n})(i^n)$.  Once you remove that, what you wrote would actually expand as the following:  $\sum\limits_{n=3}^5(\sqrt{n})(i^n)=-i\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+i\sqrt{5}$

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are after $$-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt4-\sqrt5+\sqrt6$$
Suppose instead it was:
$$\sqrt3+\sqrt4+\sqrt5+\sqrt6$$
Then in summation notation we would write this as
$$\sum_{n=3}^{6}{\sqrt n}$$
To deal with the sign flipping, we use $(-1)^n$, because $(-1)^n=1$ if $n$ is *even*, and $(-1)^n=-1$ if $n$ is *odd*.
Hence our series becomes 
$$\sum_{n=3}^{6}{(-1)^n\sqrt n}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$-\sqrt3+\sqrt4 + -\sqrt5 +\sqrt6 = \sum_{n=3}^6 (-1)^n(\sqrt n )$$

works better.

Comment: watch your equals sign placements.

Comment: @amWhy commas are not a good substitute for addition symbols.

Comment: Ohh, spoil sport, @JMoravitz  :-)   (I was actually correcting/editing while your comment was posted.  Silly me).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Consider the similar sequence$$\sqrt3,\sqrt4,\sqrt5,\sqrt6$$and write the summation form for that. Now consider your sum, identify the differences, and make changes accordingly.